# Collaborative reading of a PDF (+ chat)

Tags: gratis, web-apps, pdf, collaboration, reading

I'm looking for a software (or a site) [or even a combination of many] where two people can collaborate by reading a PDF where anyone can underline things and highlight them, while at the same time they can chat together. It would be great if it has MathJax or LaTeX support.

OS: Linux or Windows XP

I know no software or site that can make that. Google Docs is great but is only limited to *.ppt, Excel, and Word files and their equivalents.

Answer (score 2):

[Adobe Acrobat](https://acrobat.adobe.com/)/Reader and [Foxit PhantomPDF](https://www.foxitsoftware.com/pdf-editor/)/Reader have "shared review" functionality that does something similar to what you have suggested with PDF files - comments made by one person are automatically shared to all other people participating in the review. However, there's no chat functionality, and at least one person needs to have the paid software (Acrobat or PhantomPDF) to initiate the shared review.

Answer (score 0):

I believe [ShareLatex](https://www.sharelatex.com) will do as you require. Although I've never used it for collaboration the ability does exist and also has \ place to chat with those you collaborate with. An account can be created for free on ShareLatex, which is the type of account I have, or you can pay for the service if the features you desire aren't available in the free membership.

If you choose to use this service you have two options for highlighting or underlining.  The first option is to underline or highlight using the LaTeX code itself.  The second option is you could share the document using Google Drive (Docs) and highlight or underline using the [DocHub](https://dochub.com/) plugin.  Unfortunately using Drive with DocHub integration is not as seamless as using the ShareLatex method.

Comment: I already know ShareLatex, it wont allow for the type of things I explained.

Comment: Okay, well their is always the DocHub method I also mentioned.  The main problem with that is that every person would need to access the document using DocHub to see the highlights and such.  The chat could take place using Google Hangouts.